# GetHashCode of System.Type returns different values

Tags: c#, hash, types, gethashcode

Why does `GetHashCode` returns different values for the same type. If i execute this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Guid).GetHashCode());
```

In different applications, i get different hash codes.

If i execute the following statement multiple times in different applications:

```
Console.WriteLine("ABC".GetHashCode());
```

I get always the same hash code. But why is the hash code changing for `System.Type`, but not for `System.String`?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because GetHashCode for a type pointer is a hash of the pointer value (the address of the RTTI), which is going to be different between different programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither `System.String` nor `System.Type` guarantees persistable hashcodes as a part of its contract.  The fact that it so happens to work with `System.String` in your particular case is an implementation detail that cannot be relied upon.  If you need to persist or export a hash of a string, use a different string hashing method.  Persisting or exporting information about a type should probably use information like `FullName`, `AssemblyQualifiedName`, and others, depending on the exact requirement.

Comment: We want to use the GetHashCode for locking data in the database. The primary key of a lock should be the hash code of the object and it's primary key (Hash code of the primary key). Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @BendEg Yep, that's exactly how `GetHashCode` *must not be used*. It's not guaranteed safe for persistence or remoting. It is only guaranteed to be a hash code on the same machine, in the same application instance. Not to mention that hash codes are not guaranteed to be unique anyway - the only guarantee is that objects that are equal will also have equal hash codes, but not the reverse.

Comment: @Luaan thats a quite nice and important information. Than you!

Comment: [Here](http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/) Eric Lippert gives an excellent summary of how to (and not to) use `GetHashCode()`.